# Lottery winning

Tags: probability

This is a ratter simple probabilistic problem but i have not seen any similar.

My local lottery works like this:

There are 48 numbers in total (numbered from 1 to 48)
You have to pick 5 numbers from 1 to 48 (without repetition)
The lottery then draws 5 numbers (without repetition)
i) (Easy question): What are the odds of guessing the 5 of the winning numbers? ii) What are the odds of guessing exactly 4 of the 5 winning numbers? iii) What are the odds of guessing exactly 3 of the 5 winning numbers?

After drawing 5 numbers, then there is a 6th number drawn called "silver".

iv) What are the odds of guessing exactly 4 of the 5 winning numbers plus the "silver" number ? (ie: as you have picked 5 numbers, four of them have to be winning numbers and the fifth has to be silver number)

v) What are the odds of guessing exactly 3 of 5 winning number plus the "silver" number ? (ie: as you have picked 5 numbers, three of them have to be winning numbers, one silver number, and you can "miss" one of them.

In all questions, order in which numbers are picked is not important as long as you guess them.

Comment: **Hint (i) :** When the first ball is drawn, you have $5$ balls in the lottery out of a possible $48$. Then, after that ball is removed, you have $4$ balls in the lottery out of a possible $47$. Then, after that ball is removed..

Comment: i) is extremly easy, you can guess it intuitively. The problem are the other questions

Comment: Yes, but _use_ **(i)** as your starting point for **(ii)**, which gives your starting point for **(iii)** etc.

Comment: Well, i have no idea. And i am asking because i do not know tne answers (btw this is not school related)

Comment: It would help if you put what ever work you have done into your question first so I can see where the issues lie. Also, if you could explain to me what have you learnt so far we can take it from there.

Comment: What have i done is the following: i payed around 1.20 U$S to play lottery and got 3 exact winning balls. I only got paid back around 8 dollars and i just wanted to know what are the odds of that happening because i think is far greater than 8:1.20

Comment: From what i recall from probability is that Combinations(48,5) gives you the many combinations taking 5 numbers from a pool of 48. But i do not know how to calculate it when taking 5 but guessing only 4 or 3 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ${5 \choose n}$ number of ways to choose *exactly* $n$ balls from the $5$ picked.

There are ${48 - 5 \choose 5 - n}$ number of ways for the other $5 - n$ balls to come out.

There are ${48 \choose 5}$ possible combinations.

Therefore, to pick *exactly* $4$ balls from $5$ is given by

$$\begin{align} \\
\frac{{5 \choose 4} {43 \choose 1}}{48 \choose 5} &= \frac{5 \cdot 43}{1712304} \\
&= \frac{215}{1712304} \\
&= 0.00012556181 \\
\end{align}$$

To pick *exactly* $3$ balls from $5$ is given by

$$\begin{align} \\
\frac{{5 \choose 3} {43 \choose 2}}{48 \choose 5} &= \frac{10 \cdot 903}{1712304} \\
&= \frac{9030}{1712304} \\
&= 0.00527359627 \\
\end{align}$$

See how you go with the "silver" questions.

Also, for future reference, lotteries don't pay out according to what the probability of your ticket winning is (none that I know of anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I knew the odds were very low, but they are extremely low even for the "poor" prizes.

Comment: Can this be the solution to iv): [(5,4)(43,1)/(48,5)]/(42,1) ?

Comment: Try and put it in latex, it's hard to read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can part v) be like this: \begin{align} \\
\frac{{5 \choose 3} {43 \choose 2}}   {{48 \choose 5}  {5 \choose 2} {43 \choose 1}} \\
\end{align}

Comment: For $(iv)$, it is the probability that you choose _exactly_ $4$ balls, _then_ choose the silver ball ($1$ choice) from your remaining $42$ balls. So your answer was correct. Think about why your part $(v)$ might be wrong..

Comment: iv) \begin{align} \\ \frac{{5 \choose 3} {1 \choose 1}{42 \choose 2} }   {{48 \choose 5}} \\ \end{align} and v) iv) \begin{align} \\ \frac{{5 \choose 4} {1 \choose 1}{42 \choose 1} }   {{48 \choose 5}} \\ \end{align}

Comment: Hi! long time no seen. Can you tell me if the above forms are correct?

Comment: **iv)** $$\frac{{5 \choose 4} {43 \choose 1}}{48 \choose 5} \times \frac{1}{42}$$

**v)** $$\frac{{5 \choose 3} {43 \choose 2}}{48 \choose 5} \times \frac{2}{42}$$